# Zero-value colour in matplotlib hexbin

Tags: python, matplotlib, plot

I have some spatially-distributed data. I'm plotting this with `matplotlib.pyplot.hexbin` and would like to change the "background" (i.e. zero-value) colour. An example is shown below - my colour-map of choice is `matplotlib.cm.jet`:

[image: Example data]

How can I change the base colour from blue to white? I have done something similar with masked arrays when using `pcolormesh`, but I can't see anyway of doing so in the `hexbin` arguments. My instinct would be to edit the colourmap itself, but I've not had much experience with that.

I'm using matplotlib v.0.99.1.1

Answer (score 22, accepted):

`hexbin(x,y,mincnt=1)` should do the trick. Essentially, you only want to display the hexagons with more than 1 count in them.

```
from numpy import linspace
from numpy.random import normal
from pylab import hexbin,show

n = 2**6

x = linspace(-1,1,n)
y = normal(0,1,n)

h = hexbin(x,y,gridsize=10,mincnt=0)
```

gives,
[image: Bins with zero counts included]

and `h = hexbin(x,y,gridsize=10,mincnt=1)` gives,
[image: Bin count starts at one]

Comment: Great! I don't know how I missed that arg, it's there plain-as-day in the pydoc! Thanks

Comment: @Dave: No problem. It took me a while to figure it out as well.