# How can I set the zero-value color in weighted matplotlib hexbin

Tags: python, matplotlib

I would like bins with zero count to have a color when using matplotlib hexbin, similar to this question [Zero-value colour in matplotlib hexbin](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5402898/zero-value-colour-in-matplotlib-hexbin), except that I want the background color to be there. It works fine when there are no weights, but doesn't seem to work when a weight array is added (using `C=weights`).

```
from numpy import linspace
from numpy.random import normal
from pylab import hexbin,show

n = 2**6

x = linspace(-1,1,n)
y = normal(0,1,n)

h = hexbin(x,y,C=x, gridsize=10) # empty bins appear white
```

Comment: I think there is a reason why the empty bins don't have a color if a weight is used, namely that the value of the empty bin is not clearly defined or 0, but being empty should still be different from a value being weighted with zero.  Can't you just colorize the background in the color you want to achieve the desired plot?

Comment: @ImportanceOfBeingErnest I don't quite understand that, isn't an empty bin just 0 independent of how the other values are weighted? It still seems to me that it would be more consistent to assign an empty bin to the 0 of the colormap. I agree with the background color fix though, that works!

Comment: You have no way to distinguish a bin with weight 0 and an empty bin if they are both colored the same.

Comment: ok agreed. In my case I actually want them to be the same, but I'll just fix that with setting the background.